# How to get the value in array of object in MongoDB with Java syntax in Rest API

Tags: arrays, mongodb, spring-boot

I am new to Mongodb and spring boot ,trying to get the value  from Array Mongodb field .Document is like below:
I need value of Result from the below document from Email Systems.
Could you please suggest the syntax in Java

**Email Systems--->ORA-->Result-->Value**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0df36c3e870e631865877e"), 
    "user" : "Grid",  
    " Systems" : [
        "ORA", 
        "SAP", 
        "CHET"
       
    ], 
    "Email Systems" : [
        {
            "ORA" : {
                "System" : "ORA", 
                "Result" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "SAP" : {
                "System" : "WCWS", 
                "Result" : false
            }
        }
    ], 

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

import java.util.List;

public class EmailSystems {

    @Field(value = "Email Systems")
    private List<ORA> EmailSystems;

    @Field(value = "Email Systems")
    private List<SAP> EmailSAPPSystems;
    
    public List<ORA> getEmailSystems() {
        return EmailSystems;
    }

    public void setEmailSystems(List<ORA> emailSystems) {
        EmailSystems = emailSystems;
    }

    public List<SAP> getEmailSAPPSystems() {
        return EmailSAPPSystems;
    }

    public void setEmailSAPPSystems(List<SAP> emailSAPPSystems) {
        EmailSAPPSystems = emailSAPPSystems;
    }
   
}
```

One More POJO CLASS

public class ORA
{

```
private String System;

private Boolean Result;

public String getSystem() {
    return System;
}

public void setSystem(String system) {
    System = system;
}

public Boolean getResult() {
    return Result;
}

public void setResult(Boolean result) {
    Result = result;
}
```

}

I have so many systems are defined in the document as shown above Like ORA , SAP .Do I need to create that many number of POJO like ORA .Please suggest .

Comment: can you post your model class?

Comment: Added Model Class in Summary

Comment: I think since you are a beginner, you must need to read some tutorials or videos how to implement spring-boot and mongodb project https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-mongodb-crud/

Comment: I have done the implementaton , the issue is not able to get the arrays of array object in Mongodb .How to get the result value for multiple systems   "Email Systems" : [
        {
            "ORA" : {
                "System" : "ORA", 
                "Result" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "SAP" : {
                "System" : "WCWS", 
                "Result" : false
            }
        }
    ],

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, it is not a good practice to use keys with spaces and all. It is better if you follow a format for all the keys in the document as I could see so many unnecessary spaces in the keys which will not give appropriate results when searched for.
Please find the sample doc which I have modified the above one.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f0df36c3e870e631865877e"),
"user": "Grid",
"systems": ["ORA", "WCWS", "CHET"],
"email_systems" : [
    {
        "system" : "ORA",
        "subsystem": "ORA",
        "result": true
    },
    {
        "system" : "SAP",
        "subsystem": "WCWS",
        "result": false
    }]
 }
```

Please find the models below:

```
class System {

     private String system;
     private String subSystem;
     private boolean result;
}

class MainDocument {
     private List<String> systems;
     private String user;

     @Field(value = "email_systems")
     private List<System> emailSystems;
}
```

Please find below the query to get the result for the given systems:

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({"email_systems.system":{$in: ["ORA", "SAP"]}},{"email_systems.system":1,"email_systems.result":1})
```

Within find query, first braces {} is for writing the condition & the second one is for specifying fields to be returned in the response. 1 - required in the output, 0 - not required in the output